# Expected struct `Box` found closure - Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a globally accessible undo/redo functionality in my Rust app via the [undo crate](https://github.com/evenorog/undo). Additionally I am using `enum_dispatch` to handle the dynamic dispatch of my `dyn AppActions`, such as `AddName`. I start by creating a lazy static which contains my app's data model, `APP_STATE:AppState`, which has field `history` of type `undo::history::History`. In order to give History the correct trait constraints, I need to use `undo::record::Builder` to create a `Record<AppActionEnum,  Box<dyn FnMut(Signal) + Send + Sync>>`, then pass that record into `History::from()`:

```rust
use undo::{Action, History, Merged, Signal, record::Builder};
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;
lazy_static::lazy_static!{
    static ref APP_STATE: AppState = AppState::new();
}

pub struct AppState{
    names: Vec<String>,
    history: History<AppActionEnum, Box<dyn FnMut(Signal) + Send + Sync>>
}

impl AppState{
    pub fn new()->Self{
         //build should be of type <AppActionEnum, Box<dyn FnMut(Signal) + Send + Sync>>
         let build = Builder::new()
             .limit(100)
             .capacity(100)
             .connect(|s| { dbg!(s); })
             //.connect(Box::new(|s| { dbg!(s); })) gives error:
             //"expected trait object `dyn FnMut`, found closure"
             .build::<AppActionEnum>();
       
    
        AppState{
            names: vec![],
            history: History::from(build),
        }
    }
    //..
}

pub struct AddName(String);
impl AddName{
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Self{
        AddName(name.clone())
    }
}

#[enum_dispatch]
pub enum AppActionEnum {
    DoAddName(AddName),
}

#[enum_dispatch(AppActionEnum)]
pub trait AppAction: Send + Sync{
    //..
}

impl AppAction for AddName{
    //..
}

impl Action for AppActionEnum {
    //..
}
```

However this yields error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:31:22
24 |              .connect(|s| { dbg!(s); })
   |                       ---------------- the found closure
...
31 |             history: History::from(build),
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found closure
```

How do I pass a Box<(dyn FnMut(Signal) + Send + Sync + 'static)>> instead of a closure? I don't understand how what I'm doing here is different from [this example from the undo repo](https://github.com/evenorog/undo/blob/master/src/record.rs):

```rust
 //Builder for a Record.
 use undo::{Action, record::Builder, Record};
 struct Add(char);
 impl Action for Add {
     type Target = String;
     type Output = ();
     type Error = &'static str;
     fn apply(&mut self, s: &mut String) -> undo::Result<Add> {
         s.push(self.0);
         Ok(())
     }
     fn undo(&mut self, s: &mut String) -> undo::Result<Add> {
         self.0 = s.pop().ok_or("s is empty")?;
         Ok(())
     }
 }
 let _ = Builder::new()
     .limit(100)
     .capacity(100)
     .connect(|s| { dbg!(s); })
     .build::<Add>();
```

Comment: Try to change the line `.connect(|s| { dbg!(s); })` to `.connect(Box::new( |s| { dbg!(s); } ))`

Comment: @Dmitry I edited the question to show that I get error  ```expected trait object `dyn FnMut`, found closure``` when I Box the closure as you suggest

Comment: Ah, different types. Then try to use `Box::from` instead of `Box::new`

Comment: Maybe `.connect(Box::new(|s| { dbg!(s); }) as _)` (in order to convert `Box<impl Fn>` to `Box<dyn Fn>`). But it's still strange that the example from the documentation works without boxing it. I expect that `connect` is supposed to do the boxing, but that fails for some reason.

Comment: @user4815162342: That is because the type of the argument to `connect()` is actually the second generic argument of the type. The example lets it unspecified, so it is deduced by the call to `connect()`, but OP's code writes it explicitly in the definition of `AppState`.

Comment: @user4815162342 are you implying that the failure of the boxing is due to an error in the undo crate?

Comment: No, I was just pointing out the thing I didn't understand, which was since clarified by rodrigo. I would now expect `Box::from(...)` or `Box::new(...) as _` to solve the issue, but you didn't specify whether that worked. In general, it's hard to answer this question without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: ```Box::new(...) as _``` worked!  ```Box::from(...)``` did not however.